# ASSERT: "first <= rowCount(parent)" in file itemmodels\qabstractitemmodel.cpp

Tags: c++, qt, tableview

Проект собирается, и, как только открывается окно, сразу же выдает ошибку (причём указанного в ошибке файла вовсе не существует):

```
ASSERT: "first <= rowCount(parent)" in file itemmodels\qabstractitemmodel.cpp
```

Насколько я понимаю, ошибка в переопределённом виртуальном методе `rowCount()`. Но, пока что, я не понимаю как это исправить. Буду рад любой помощи.

```cpp
int QTableViewModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &) const
{
    return values->size();
}
```

Comment: Если нужно, могу прикрепить весь код.

Comment: Надо больше информации, а так только одни подозрения

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Что именно вас интересует?

Comment: Скорее всего ошибка в индексах `beginInsertRows`. У вас первый индекс `first` больше чем количество строк в модели, о чём и говорит ошибка

Comment: @needKVAS ДА, так и есть. Поправил это, теперь всё работает, большое спасибо)

Comment: Так в итоге, как вы разрешили эту ошибку?

Comment: @resusfactor_228 Поменял индекс для beginInsertRows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена, но от себя добавлю, что `rowCount` реализуется немного по-другому:

```
int TableModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return parent.isValid() ? 0 : contacts.size();
}
```

(взято из Qt'шного example'а).